# Magento developer coding question (Upwork)

Tags: json, magento2

I have hired a developer through UpWork to develop a Magento Webshop. One of the benefits if UpWork is that you can see the working hours and the files she has been working in. She has billed me for 120 hours for only working in these files:

As I am not familiar with Magento and not being a developer (only familiar with html, css, and php basics). I was wondering if anyone can tell me if it makes sense to work that many hours in the files below.

Monday 6 Aug 2018 (7:30hours)

C:\Users\Chetan\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\index.php - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\Chetan\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\package.json.sample - Notepad++

Tuesday 7 Aug 2018 (7:50hours)

C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\composer.lock - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\index.php - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\php.ini.sample - Notepad++

Wednesday 8 Aug 2018 (8:50hours)

C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\package.json.sample - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\composer.json - Notepad++

Thursday 9 Aug 2018 (6:30hours)

C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\index.php - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\composer.json - Notepad++

Saturday 11 Aug 2018 (3:20hours)

No active windows 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\composer.json - Notepad++ 
Program Manager

Monday 13 Aug 2018 (7:40hours)

C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\composer.json - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\index.php - Notepad++

Tuesday 14 Aug 2018 (8:40hours)

C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\composer.json - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\package.json.sample - Notepad++

Thursday 16 Aug 2018 (7:00hours)

C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\composer.json - Notepad++ 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\package.json.sample - Notepad++ 
Magento Digital Commerce - Google Chrome 
C:\Users\redefined\Downloads\magento-2-community-sample-data-master\Gruntfile.js.sample - Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Certified Magento Developer here.
composer.json is a file that holds dependencies so you will have to update those when changing dependencies. 
However, working on these files THIS LONG is not right. none of those are taking this long to modify and considering the developer used Notepad++, (s)he should definitely not work with magento. This requires some reasonable IDE progam like Netbeans, Eclipse or PHPStorm to work with Magento really well.
index.php is barely changed during development, too.
the files pointed are also sample data, which should not be worked on either. 
Looks like smeone didn't knew what (s)he's been up to.